# examples of smooth manifold which is not Hausdorff or not second countable

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In differential geometry, a Hausdorff smooth manifold whose topology has a countable basis has good property. However, I don't know examples which is smooth but not Hausdorff or not second-countable.

Could you teach me a couple of examples? Is there geometrically interesting one?

Comment: Non Hausdorff: gluing to $\mathbb R$'s along $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. Non second countable: Uncountable disjoint unions of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Another one that's not second countable: the [Prüfer manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_manifold).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hausdorff but not second-countable: Take the product of $\mathbb R$ with its standard topology and $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology. The intuition here is an uncountably infinite family of copies of $\mathbb R$, all separated from each other.

Non-Hausdorff: consider $\mathbb R \times \{0,1\}$ and identify $(x,0) = (x,1)$ whenever $x<0$. Around any given point this looks like $\mathbb R$, but the points $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ cannot be separated by neighbourhoods.